# PHPExcel create PDF

Tags: php, pdf-generation, phpexcel

I am having a problem creating a PDF using PHPExcel. I can create the excel and pdf file fine, but its the characters on the pdf that isn't working properly. Image below.

[image]

If I copy any of the text and paste it somewhere it reads as normal text and not gibberish anymore, which is very strange. My code is below.

```
$newpdf = "reports/risk-bordereaux-".$time.".pdf";
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($newxlsx);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getPageSetup()->setPaperSize(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A4);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getPageSetup()->setFitToWidth(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getPageSetup()->setFitToHeight(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setShowGridlines(false);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
$objWriter->save($newpdf);
```

I'm wondering is there any way I could set the character encoding or something to stop this happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Link to [bigger image](http://postimg.org/image/biz15dwd3/fb8a7a15/)

I am using TCPDF to generate PDF's

Comment: The image is way too small, please give us a link to a bigger version.

Comment: The PDF should be generated with UTF-8 characters, but which PDF rendering engine are you using?

Comment: Finally by right click / open image in new tab, I can see it. What's the `$newxlsx` variable ?

Comment: Updated my question. $newxlsx is the path to the excel file.

Comment: Have a look at following threads : 

https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/208838 and this 
http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/12513 I think this should

it's seems to me issue with encoding

Comment: Sorry no luck with that. Still producing the same characters.